# Can't find ruby 2.2.x stable in my rbenv install list

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I was expecting to see the latest stable ruby version 2.2.2 and also 2.2.3 which has just been released when running:

```
rbenv install --list
```

I did an update to rbenv using `git pull` and `rbenv rehash`.

Do I need to clear a cache for those versions to show up?

My version list is:

```
Available versions:
  1.8.6-p383
  1.8.6-p420
  1.8.7-p249
  1.8.7-p302
  1.8.7-p334
  1.8.7-p352
  1.8.7-p357
  1.8.7-p358
  1.8.7-p370
  1.8.7-p371
  1.8.7-p374
  1.8.7-p375
  1.9.1-p378
  1.9.1-p430
  1.9.2-p0
  1.9.2-p180
  1.9.2-p290
  1.9.2-p318
  1.9.2-p320
  1.9.2-p326
  1.9.3-dev
  1.9.3-p0
  1.9.3-p125
  1.9.3-p194
  1.9.3-p286
  1.9.3-p327
  1.9.3-p362
  1.9.3-p374
  1.9.3-p385
  1.9.3-p392
  1.9.3-p429
  1.9.3-p448
  1.9.3-p484
  1.9.3-preview1
  1.9.3-rc1
  2.0.0-dev
  2.0.0-p0
  2.0.0-p195
  2.0.0-p247
  2.0.0-p353
  2.0.0-preview1
  2.0.0-preview2
  2.0.0-rc1
  2.0.0-rc2
  2.1.0
  2.1.0-dev
  2.1.0-preview1
  2.1.0-preview2
  2.1.0-rc1
  2.2.0-dev
  jruby-1.5.6
  jruby-1.6.3
  jruby-1.6.4
  jruby-1.6.5
  jruby-1.6.5.1
  jruby-1.6.6
  jruby-1.6.7
  jruby-1.6.7.2
  jruby-1.6.8
  jruby-1.7.0
  jruby-1.7.0-preview1
  jruby-1.7.0-preview2
  jruby-1.7.0-rc1
  jruby-1.7.0-rc2
  jruby-1.7.1
  jruby-1.7.10
  jruby-1.7.2
  jruby-1.7.3
  jruby-1.7.4
  jruby-1.7.5
  jruby-1.7.6
  jruby-1.7.7
  jruby-1.7.8
  jruby-1.7.9
  maglev-1.0.0
  maglev-1.1.0-dev
  maglev-2.0.0-dev
  mruby-dev
  rbx-1.2.4
  rbx-2.0.0
  rbx-2.0.0-dev
  rbx-2.0.0-rc1
  rbx-2.1.0
  rbx-2.1.1
  rbx-2.2.0
  rbx-2.2.1
  rbx-2.2.2
  rbx-2.2.3
  ree-1.8.6-2009.06
  ree-1.8.7-2009.09
  ree-1.8.7-2009.10
  ree-1.8.7-2010.01
  ree-1.8.7-2010.02
  ree-1.8.7-2011.03
  ree-1.8.7-2011.12
  ree-1.8.7-2012.01
  ree-1.8.7-2012.02
  topaz-dev
```

How will I get the 2.2.x stable versions to show up? 
Or better, how do I tell `ruby-build` to fetch new definitions?

I am on Linux BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to update the ruby-build plugin inside the ~/.rbenv/plugins/ directory using:

```
cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git pull
```

Could this not be automated?

Answer (score 1):

rbenv supports [plugins](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Plugins), of which "[update](https://github.com/rkh/rbenv-update)" will do what you want.

From the docs:

> update rbenv and installed plugins

```
mkdir -p "$(rbenv root)/plugins"
git clone https://github.com/rkh/rbenv-update.git "$(rbenv root)/plugins/rbenv-update"
```

Then run `rbenv update` and it'll refresh rbenv and any other plugins you've added.

It might be useful to add that to a daily or weekly cron task so rbenv is automatically updated regularly.